# Position html element so that child element is centered on the page

Tags: html, css

How can I position a parent div, so a specific child div is vertically centered on the page (or alternatively positioned at the top of the page)? The child divs' relative position to each other and their parent should not be affected by what child element is centered. Can it be done with CSS only? Or do I need to use JavaScript?

```
<div class="parent">
  <div>1</div>   <!-- This div will most likely be invisible above the page top -->
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  ...
  <div id="centered">567</div> <!-- This div will be vertically centered on the page -->
  ...
  <div>998</div>
  <div>999</div>
  <div>1000</div>  <!-- This div will most likely be invisible below the page bootom -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a bit of javascript I'm afraid. See the `scrollIntoView` method on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

```js
window.onload = () => {
  const element = document.querySelector("#centered");
  element.scrollIntoView({
    behavior: "smooth",
    block: "center",
    inline: "center"
  });
  console.log("Done!!");
}
```

```css
#centered {
  background-color: gold;
}

.parent>div {
  padding: 2rem 0.5rem;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  margin-block: 0.25rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>1</div>
  <!-- This div will most likely be invisible above the page top -->
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
  <div id="centered">567</div>
  <!-- This div will be vertically centered on the page -->
  <div>990</div>
  <div>991</div>
  <div>992</div>
  <div>993</div>
  <div>994</div>
  <div>995</div>
  <div>996</div>
  <div>997</div>
  <div>998</div>
  <div>999</div>
  <div>1000</div>
  <!-- This div will most likely be invisible below the page bootom -->
</div>
```